# Rails 3 Authlogic - 'acts_as_authentic' undefined

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I'm getting the following error:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `acts_as_authentic' for #<Class:0x1037e6310>):
  app/models/user.rb:2
  app/controllers/user_controller.rb:3:in `new'
```

I'm using Rails 3.0.0, with Ruby 1.8.7. Authlogic is in my Gemfile as follows:

```
gem 'authlogic', :git => "git://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic.git"
```

The entire contents of my User.rb file are as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   acts_as_authentic 
end
```

I get the same error whether through 'rails console' or through the server. I have restarted the server more times than I can count. Please help, I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Use a version of authlogic patched for Rails 3

```
gem 'authlogic', :git => 'git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git', :branch => 'rails3'
```

Or even better. Use Devise

Answer (score 0):

Is the Authlogic Gem installed ?.

Please do

```
Bundle install
```

this should solve your problem.

Comment: It's installed. that's not the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
gem "authlogic",   "2.1.6"
```

Then

```
Bundle install
```

Hope it'll helpfull for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

create a file in `config/initializers` as `restful_authentication.rb` 
and paste this inside the file and restart server and try

```
require 'authenticated_system'
require 'restful_authentication/authentication'
require 'restful_authentication/authentication/by_password'
require 'restful_authentication/authentication/by_cookie_token'
require 'restful_authentication/authorization/aasm_roles'
require 'restful_authentication/authorization/stateful_roles'
require 'restful_authentication/trustification/email_validation'
```